# .NET Core API List<IFormFile> files not received from .NET MVC MultipartFormDataContent POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core API POST method below:

```
    public IActionResult UploadFiles([FromForm(Name = "files")] List<IFormFile> files, [FromForm(Name = "providerName")] string providerName) 
    {
        try
        {
            return WriteToXlsx(files,providerName); //documents
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

It works fine when posting from Postman, files are received.
However when trying to post from ASP.NET MVC as shown below, it appears the files are not being received. there is no error message, but the file count from List files is zero. The string "providerName" is being received.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ContentTransformation(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string providerName)
    {
      
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                byte[] fileData;
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
                {
                    fileData = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
                }
                var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
                multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "files");
            }

            StringContent sProviderName = new StringContent(providerName);
            multipartFormDataContent.Add(sProviderName, "\"providerName\"");

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentTransformationAPI"], multipartFormDataContent);

            FileContentResult metadataContent = new FileContentResult(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

            return File(
                fileContents: metadataContent.FileContents,
                contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                fileDownloadName: "metadata.xlsx"
                );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!! " + ex.Message;
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It'll be a problem with the view you're POSTing from. The form input element must be called `files`, to match your `files` parameter in your controller's action, otherwise the model binder won't pick it up.

Comment: Hi @JohnH it is called "files":
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />

Comment: @user2248185 is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` in `ContentTransformation` empty?

Comment: @GuruStron it is not empty and has the uploaded files

Comment: I just figured it out. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

I've found the problem. You're discarding the `FileName` of the uploads, so it doesn't bind properly when you POST the data from your MVC controller to your API controller. All you need to change is:

```
multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "files");
```

to

```
multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent, "files", file.FileName);
```

and then the files will be bound properly.

#### Old answer

Your code (controller + form element) works for me, which makes me think it's your form you've not setup properly. At its simplest, it should look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "ContentTransformation", 
    "YourControllerName", // Make sure you change this.
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

I think the part you might be missing is the `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }`. The `multipart/form-data` enctype is what allows input elements to upload file data, so your uploader won't work without it.

Comment: OP trying to send files with `HttpClient`.

Comment: @GuruStron Check the comments please. The OP is using a form with an input element.

Comment: I've already removed it. Though from OP's answers it is still not clear that problem is in posting to `ContentTransformation`.

Comment: @GuruStron I see what you're saying - the second paragraph of the question is ambiguous, so it could mean the problem is the posting of the form, or it could be the part posting from MVC -> the API.

Comment: Thanks @JohnH, adding file.FileName solved my problem!